# Can you perform a jQuery function based element's pseudo class?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to write a jQuery function that will trigger when another element has and doesn't have pseudo class?

For example, when element A is being hovered on elements C's class should be "aishovered" and when it is not, it should go back to "anothovered"

When A not hovered:

```
<div class="a"> </div>
<div class="b"> </div>
<div class="c anothovered"> </div>
```

When A is hovered:

```
<div class="a"> </div>
<div class="b"> </div>
<div class="c aishovered"> </div>
```

Hover state is just being used for an example, looking for a jQuery solution that works with other pseudo classes such as :active and :visited.

Answer (score 0):

To actually add and remove a class, for `:hover` you can respond to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, via [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
$(".a").hover(
    function() { $(".c").addClass("aishovered").removeClass("anothovered");},
    function() { $(".c").removeClass("aishovered").addClass("anothovered");}
);
```

...and for `:active` you can handle `focus` and `blur`.

But for pseudo-classes *in general*, you have to stick to CSS solutions. In your case, since the elements are siblings, you can do that with a [sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#sibling-combinators):

```css
.a:hover ~ .c {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">a</div>
<div class="b">b</div>
<div class="c">c</div>
```

That doesn't literally add and remove a class, but it adds and removes styling.

Comment: What about for an active state?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".a").hover(
   function () {
     $('.c').addClass("aishovered");
     $('.c').removeClass("anothovered");
   },
   function () {
     $('.c').addClass("anothovered");
     $('.c').removeClass("aishovered");
   }
);
```

Check link Below

http://jsfiddle.net/e27Dt/1836/